# Реально ли написать свою криптовалюту на Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, криптография, bitcoin

Реально ли если уже есть свой blockchain на Python написать под него Coin (криптовалюту) на Рython?

Comment: На каком угодно тьюринг-полном языке реально, нужно лишь чтобы хватило умений и выдержки для написания

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Да, реально, это уже реализовали.
**GitHub:** https://github.com/dvf/blockchain